# nodejs express Why not return res?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to finish if isBookmark is true
Enter the then below and console.log(1); This works, I hope it doesn't work

```
checkLecture(addLectureInformation)
        .then(() => {
            return insertLecture(addLectureInformation);
        })
        .then((succesInsertLecture) => {
            if (true) {
                return res.status(200).json(succesInsertLecture);
            } else {
                return Promise.all([1]);
            }
        })
        .then(num => {
            console.log(1);
        })
```

Help

Comment: `This works, I hope it doesn't work` ? Sorry your question is hard to understand, could you please explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: `if (true) { ... } else { ... }` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't speak English well

What I want is "return res.status(200).json(succesInsertLecture);" code to end here

Answer (score 0):

You can't skip steps in your promise chain, but you can move the last then so it is not called if you returned a response already:

```
checkLecture(addLectureInformation)
        .then(() => {
            return insertLecture(addLectureInformation);
        })
        .then((succesInsertLecture) => {
            // this should be other condition, because this will be true always and "else" is not even needed/run
            if (true) {
                return res.status(200).json(succesInsertLecture);
            } else {
                // Moving the last "then" here, so it is not called is you have sent a response already
                return Promise.all([Promise.resolve(1)]) // Promise all expects an array of promises
                         .then(num => {
                           console.log(1);
                         })
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you really think `Promise.all([1]).then(num => { console.log(1); })` is a good idea?

Comment: I don't see why it is a bad idea, can you explain please? I guess he made an example (agree is not a really good example) trying to understand promises.

Comment: It makes no sense. The array `[1]` doesn't contain any promises. Why would you call `Promise.all` on it? The callback is immediately triggered. Why do you even need a callback? Why does the callback function have a parameter if it's always logging `1`? You could replace `return Promise.all([1]).then(num => { console.log(1); })` with `console.log(1);`

Comment: It is a bad example, I agree, but I think that he is trying to understand why console.log is called if he already returned a response before. The promise is not stopping after he returns the response, so, if he really wants to avoid the execution of the last then, he should just move that to the else statement. I can delete the answer too if you think it is wrong, not a big deal.

Comment: The array is just an example, we will ask for something else in Promise.all